# Magento 2 (Installation is incomplete at 73%) Module 'Magento_Weee'

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, installation, magento2

so I just started to learn using Magento 2 and I'm blocked from the start :/ I looked in many sites before for my problem I found solutions but none of them did solve my problem, I hope you have an idea guys!
so I got :
Installation is incomplete. 
Check the console log for errors before trying again.
and it stops in this point :

> Module 'Magento_Weee':
>   Installing data... 
>   [ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Nom du champ 'weee_tax_disposition' déjà utilisé in C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `qu...', Array) #5 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(515): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE`qu...', Array) #6 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(578): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('ALTER TABLE `qu...', Array) #7 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(433): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE`qu...') #8 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(952): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->rawQuery('ALTER TABLE `qu...') #9 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\app\code\Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup.php(126): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->addColumn('quote_item', 'weee_tax_dispos...', 'decimal(12,4) N...') #10 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\app\code\Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup.php(102): Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup->_addFlatAttribute('quote_item', 'weee_tax_dispos...', Array) #11 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\app\code\Magento\Weee\Setup\InstallData.php(60): Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup->addAttribute('quote_item', 'weee_tax_dispos...', Array) #12 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(867): Magento\Weee\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #13 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(791): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data') #14 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() #15 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #16 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #17 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #18 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #19 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #20 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(214): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #21 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #22 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #23 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #24 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #25 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(214): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #26 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #27 C:\wamp64\www\magento2\setup\index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #28 {main}

it said that the column exists but I checked in my database , the column does not exist :/
I tried to change the max_input_time,max_execution_time  and memory_limit  in php.ini and I restarted wamp but still have the same error!!
Thanks in advance
I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys finally :'( , I hope this will help many of you!
This is what I did after too many tries :
First I got Installation is incomplete each time at 73%
so

=>1) in php.ini change max_execution_time = 180000 --and --memory_limit = 2G

2) drop the database, create again and relaunch wamp

3) refresh and reinstall Magento2

Than I thought that finished but again I got a new problem :D

Installation is incomplete each time at 94%

=> 1) so you go in yourfolder\app\code\Magento\Tax\Setup\RecurringData.php 
you put this line after line 69
 if (empty($taxRateData->getData('percentage_rate'))) continue;

//After installation I've removed the line 70

2) refresh the page of installation and you're done :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a week, always getting stuck on 72% tried everything, I then decided to install without sample data and it installed straight away.